# Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge Chrome Both Crash Instantly Upon Launching

Tags: windows-server-2016, google-chrome, symantec-endpoint-protection, microsoft-edge

I have a single Windows server (Windows Server 2016 / 1607) which has peculiar issues with web browsers.

Both Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge Chrome crash instantly when they are launched and display the `Aw Snap` / `This Page is having a problem` error respectively, even when I launch the about:chrome page.

IE11 on the other hand works perfectly.

First I thought it was the Chrome / Symantec bug from a couple of months ago, but I've already implemented policies enterprise-wide to fix that particular issue.

I've tried the following:

- Reinstalling latest version of Chrome
- Installing latest version of Edge Chrome
- Disabling Symantec Endpoint Protection (SEP)
- Updating SEP to 14.2.xxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue, it was Symantec Endpoint Protection all along, it just wasn't having it with any possible file level exception, removing SEP and reinstalling it fixed the issue.